# Print button functionality not working in Google chrome

Tags: javascript

I have print button in web page, and I am trying to print the page but first time when I click on on print the preview is not loaded and again when I click on print the content is loading. Please let me know anyone have any idea, below is the code I am using.

```
$('#printButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href').length === 1) {
        window.print();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
                TEST.printContent(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you showing print button dynamic? IF yes then you have to perform [http://api.jquery.com/on/] On function in Jquery

Comment: No, print button is not dynamic. It's just anchor tag which I am performing print action.

Comment: Make sure that you have written this script in document.ready state.

Comment: It is in  document.ready function. Please suggest if you have any solution.